# What are the names and purposes of these six kitchen knives?

Tags: equipment, knives

My longtime neighbor had this collection of six GONON-GIRONDE high-carbon steel knives that she inherited from her mother. I thought that they were incredible, and must be wonderful to use.

Sadly she passed away, and her husband, who does not cook, knowing that I coveted the knives, gave them to me. They are a joy to use, and I think of her every time I get one of them out. The patina on them was there when I received them, and knowing that they are high-carbon steel, and stain easily, I clean and dry them immediately after each use. I also bought a nice whet stone set which permits me to put an exceptional edge on the blades.

I've assigned a number to each knife in the attached photo, and I would like to know the formal name and purpose of each knife. I am assuming that numbers 3-5 are chef knives, and that's how I use them. And I recognize number 2 as being the style of knife often used to carve smoked brisket here in east Texas (and it performs that task perfectly), but I am pretty confident that there's more to it than my simple observations. In additional, I am keen to know the name and purpose of numbers 1 and 6. (By the way, number 6 has a sharp edge, so I doubt that it is a bread knife.)

Any information that can be offered will be gratefully appreciated.

[image: Six GONON-GIRONDE high-carbon steel knives]

Comment: Nice set of knives!  Consider polishing them.

Comment: Knives 1 and 2 are slashy knives, knives 3-5 are stabby knives, and knife 6 is a slicey knife.

Comment: What a wonderful collection.  In my experience, most home chefs only need #3 or #4 depending which feels better in their hand.  Yet, companies selling knives always try to give you as many as they can.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The first two are types of sabers.  They’re used for butchering or cutting down large hunks of meat.

The next three are chef’s knives of different sizes.

The last one is a slicer, used for when you want thin slices of cooked meat.

Comment: Dad always called #6 a "Roast Beef" knife, I have seen it referred to that here and there...

Comment: @SteveChambers: I’ve seen it called a ‘roast slicer’ or a ‘fish slicer’, but I honestly have no idea what the difference is between the two

Comment: Steve and Joe: Thanks for the additional comments. I'm glad that it's confirmed that it is a slicing knife. I thought that it looked like a knife that was used in a buffet line to slice ham. Apparently, it can slice whatever I want . I can't wait to use it, but in fact, any time I use one of these knives I get great pleasure. For example, that 14" chef knife is perfect for trimming the tops of artichokes. And every time I use one of them, I think of my dear friend.

Comment: "The first two are types of sabers. They’re used for butchering or cutting down large hunks of meat." Or for chopping up people - they have a pretty strong resemblance to certain types of old-fashioned combat knives. Also, how can you tell that #6 is for meat rather than bread? Is it the lack of serrations on the edge?

Comment: @nick012000 : true, but you really want a cleaver or something heavier if you're going through bone.  Or a saw.  The first one's more like a really large boning knife, where it's good for getting up to the bone but not going through it.  (There are plenty of butchery videos on YouTube where you'll see the first two in use -- here's [a guy cutting up a lamb who mostly uses the first style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uq_GB3ldQW8)).  And yes about the slicer -- the lack of serrations make for for a smoother cut so it's less likely to leave lines on the meat slices.

Comment: @Joe we had a question on SA  a couple months ago about whether or not there was any difference between a fish slicer and a meat slicer.  Answer: maybe.

Comment: Nick: #6 is not serrated. It has a very sharp edge, and I have confirmed that it does an exceptional job at slicing cooked meat.